# Keep track of how many times a recursive function has been called in Python

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I have a piece of Python code that implements a recursive backtracking algorithm for solving the famous N-Queens problem in chess.

```
def Backtrack(board, col):

  if col >= N:
    return True

  for i in range(N):
      if (ld[i - col + N - 1] != 1 and rd[i + col] != 1) and cl[i] != 1:
          board[i][col] = 1
          ld[i - col + N - 1] = rd[i + col] = cl[i] = 1
          if Backtrack(board, col + 1):
              return True
          board[i][col] = 0 # Backtrack 
          ld[i - col + N - 1] = rd[i + col] = cl[i] = 0

  return False
```

where

```
ld = np.zeros(2*N - 1, dtype=int)
rd = np.zeros(2*N - 1, dtype=int)
cl = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)
board = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=int)
```

### The Problem:

I want to keep a track of how many times the recursive backtracking algorithm is called.

### My Attempt:

I added a counter variable to the code such that

```
def Backtrack(board, col, counter):

  counter += 1
  print('here', counter)

  if col >= N:
    return True

  for i in range(N):
      if (ld[i - col + N - 1] != 1 and rd[i + col] != 1) and cl[i] != 1:
          board[i][col] = 1
          ld[i - col + N - 1] = rd[i + col] = cl[i] = 1
          if Backtrack(board, col + 1, counter):
              return True
          board[i][col] = 0 # Backtrack 
          ld[i - col + N - 1] = rd[i + col] = cl[i] = 0

  return False
```

however for *N = 4* the output is

```
here 1
here 2
here 3
here 3
here 4
here 2
here 3
here 4
here 5
```

which shows that my attempt is incorrect. The function is called 9 times but at the end the counter variable is 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers are immutable, so when you do `counter += 1`, you create a new number, say from 1 to 2, and 2 is now bound to the name `counter`. So when you're at depth 2 and call the function twice, both calls will increment 2 to their own 3. In python you don't pass by variable, but by name, so that `counter` isn't referring to the same thing throughout all the calls.

What you want is either a mutable or global variable. For example

```
# or a class implementation equivalent
counter = 0
def backtrack(board, col):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    # the rest
```

But that way you'd need to reset `counter` to 0 every time you want to restart the algorithm. Therefore, I think it's better to do

```
def backtrack(board, col, counter=None):
    if not counter:
        counter = [0]
    counter[0] += 1
    # the rest of your function
```

Be very careful of doing `backtrack(board, col, counter=[0])`, because `counter` will be [initialised to the list only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). After you've solved, for say N=4, it will have the value 9 and if you call the function again, it will keep incrementing from there.

Answer (score 0):

***Dirty hack:***
Use the fact that default arguments in Python are shared between function calls:

```
def Backtrack(board, col, counter = [0]):

  counter[0]+=1
  print('here', counter[0])
```

***Proper solution:***
Contain your method in a class:

```
class Board():
    counter = 0

    def Backtrack(self, board, col):

        self.counter+=1
        print('here', self.counter)
```

later called like so:

```
Board().Backtrack(board, 0)
```

Comment: Both approaches have the issue that you need to reset `counter` manually if you want to rerun the algorithm.

Comment: @Reti43 I changed the call in proper solution to fix that.

Comment: That addresses the second approach, though it may not be the best way to handle the reset as for every solution you have to instantiate the class. But the bigger issue here is with the dirty hack. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416002/2243104).